# How to send the request to url and receive the response in the xml format using php

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

The below mentioned URL Link sends a XML response in browser.  The same response is received in a variable using PHP

In single PHP page I should raise the URL request and should get the response in the same page.

```
http://localhost:8090/solr/salesreport/select?q=salesdates:[2007-05-01 TO 2014-05-15]&wt=xml&rows=10&indent=true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML(file_get_contents("http://203.196.191.92:8090/solr/salesreport/select?q=salesdates:[2007-05-01TO2014-05-13]&wt=xml&rows=10&indent=true"));
```

Comment: i Tried as you said , but it throughs error Fatal error: Call to a member function loadXML() on a non-object  where can find this function ?

Comment: @AvikarshaSaha please add some explanation to your answer why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8090/solr/salesreport/select?q='.$grystrres.'&wt=xml&rows=10&indent=true';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$variable = file_get_contents('http://203.196.191.92:8090/solr/salesreport/select?q=salesdates:[2007-05-01TO2014-05-13]&wt=xml&rows=10&indent=true');
```

Comment: In variable noting is available .. its empty only....

Comment: You are sure. Did you do view source? Because you will output xml if you just print it. Which the browser will just hide

Comment: I put echo to view the content in variable but it displays nothing.

Comment: And you did View Source? Because the web browser will treat it as HTML tags.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer why this solves the problem.

Comment: @lethal-guitar it doesnt show any error but $variable is empty.   i copy and paste the url in browser it returns some values. i want those values in the variable. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: @WizKid In View Source also not available..

Comment: What browser do you use that does not have View Source?

Comment: @lethal-guitar: It is one function. Sure I can link to php.net but if you don't know what the function does I assume you will search php.net

Comment: @Wizkid I'd assume that someone searching php.net would not ask this question in the first place.. Anyway, if you don't want to at least add a sentence to describe your code snippet, why bother answering at all? In it's current form, your answer ended up in the review queue for low quality posts. That's the reason for my comment.

Comment: The answer tells them which function to use and how to use it. Which you wouldn't find by just going to php.net. I don't feel like adding a like to php.net would make the answer better.